# How to define type-less string of 1-bits

Tags: c

I'm writing code for a flash driver and I sometimes have to check whether or not certain locations are empty i.e. contain 0xff.

Sometimes I check bytes, sometimes longer values. So I wanted to have a define that captures a type-less string of 1-bits that I can use to compare against.

It should work for signed and unsigned variables of 8, 16 and 32 bit wide.

I've tried the following two:

```
#define ERASED (-1)
#define ERASED (~0)
```

If I then compile the following code (all unsigned variables):

```
if (some32bitvar == ERASED)
{
    ....
}

if (some16bitvar == ERASED)
{
    ....
}

if (some8bitvar == ERASED)
{
    ....
}
```

The compiler is happy with the 16 and 32 bits variables, but complains about the 8 bit variable:

```
[Warning(ccom)] this comparison is always true
```

Note: The architecture and compiler are 16-bit, so an int is 16 bit.

The compiler is correct because it extends `some8bitvar` to an `int`, which yields `0x00nn`. It then compares it against `ERASED` which is also extended to an `int` and thus yields `0xffff`.

A trivial solution is to use:

```
if (~some8bitvar)
{
    ....
}
```

But that uses implicit knowledge of an erased flash, which I want to abstract out and it obscures what the statement does.

Another solution is to use:

```
if (some8bitvar == (typeof(some8bitvar)) ERASED)
{
    ....
}
```

But that makes the code less clear and my compiler doesn't support the `typeof` macro.

How can I define `ERASED` to make comparing to it work for all types?

Comment: Why can't you do `x == 0` or `x != 0`?

Comment: @snowman The `ERASED` value is 0xff, 0xffff and 0xffffffff respectively for 8-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit variables. So `not ERASED` is anything other than 0xff(ff(ffff). That includes zero, but also includes all other values up to 254 for 8-bit values, up to 65534 for 16-bit values and up to 0xfffffffe for 32-bit values. Zero is a good value to use because it is type-less, that is the reason I tried `(~0)`, but unfortunately it didn't work because the compiler (sign)extends untyped values to int. The value `zero` always yields regardless to whatever type you extend it to, but `-1` and `~0` don't.

Comment: Try `#define ERASED(value) (!(~(value)))`

Comment: @snowman I see what you mean. But my case is not about comparing two variables of different types (in particular signed/unsigned) but about comparing a variable to a constant. Comparing for equality to zero works for all types, signed, unsigned, big or small. Zero is a string of all zero bits, so I had hoped that `~0` would be a string of all 1 bits that I could use in the same way. What @rwong suggested is a very good solution. It makes it clear what is meant: `if (ERASED(somevar))` or `if(! ERASED(someothervar))`

Comment: Note that `0` is not type-less at all : it's an `int` literal.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I know. What is so special about zero is that when it is sign-extended and/or cast to a bigger or smaller type it remains the same i.e. the literal value zero is signed and unsigned at the same time and also 8-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit. Literals like `-1` and `~0` don't have that property. They are also represented in the `int` type of the machine you are compiling for (just like zero), but have a different value depending on the type you representing it in: in 8-bit it is 255, in 16-bit is it 65535, etc. That is why using it in a comparison doesn't work the same way as zero does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a macro like

```
 #define IsErased(val) ((~(val))==0)
```

and use it like

```
 if (IsErased(someXXbitvar)) ...
```

This gives you the abstraction you want and keeps the code readable.

(If your have a modern C11 compiler, you can try to implement this by overloaded  functions and the `_Generic` keyword, providing different implementations for each type). But I guess the above solution will be sufficient for your case, it is pretty simple and will also work with older compilers.

Comment: This solution (actually one based on the same idea) has been suggested already, but I think you are right: it is the simplest and most readable solution in my case. I like zero: it is the same for every type ;-)

Comment: For the record, C *does* support function overloading. https://gist.github.com/barosl/e0af4a92b2b8cabd05a7 (C11/GCC 4.9 though.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you use `char` for 8bit values, and on your compiler `char` is unsigned. When you do the comparison, the 8bit value is promoted to an int value in the range 1-255 that cannot be equal to -1.

But is your 8bit value is explicitely a signed char, it will be promoted to and int in the range -128, 127 (assuming you have no negative 0). So this code should be accepted by your compiler if it is conformant:

```
signed char val=-1;

if (val == -1) {
    // this branch will be executed
}
```

Comment: Your are right with respect to signed values. But I'm specifically looking for an approach that works for both signed and unsigned values. The answers Doc Brown and rwong gave work for signed and unsigned quantities.